# Usage of the に particle in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

The sentence reads

> 俺は派手にハッキリと命の順序を決めている

I understand the sentence as meaning "I'll establish a clear gaudy life priority" however I am confused as the the exact role に is playing. I would hazard a guess its designating the source of the action but I'm not 100% sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think the 勝手【かって】 means in this sentence?  What part of speech do you think that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

派手に describes the manner in which the priority is determined (so it doesn't describe the nature of the priority itself).

So the sentence means: `I have decided on the priority of lives, clearly and flamboyantly`

Note that if you parse the sentence correctly, it doesn't mean "your priority in life" but rather "priority of other lives (as in who should live/die)".

It's an odd sentence (also in Japanese) - I'm guessing it's from anime/manga. It's probably purposefully odd to make an impact.

Comment: Ah I see so に here is being used to the describe the manner in which the priority was decided not the nature. I assume one could use another adjective in place of 派手to change the sentence (i.e. would it be correct to replace 派手 with say 変に to change the meaning to "I have decided on the priority of lives, clearly and strangely" a little bit of an odd sentence but just for example)?

Comment: I guess it's grammatical but it's definitely odd. A more natural example would be 今日は変に白い鼻水が出る. Then 変に means 鼻水 comes out in an unusual way (like more than usual etc.) @Xanadulo

Answer (score 1):

This に ending turns the na-adjective 派手な into an adverb. A couple of more examples:

- 静かな部屋 (quiet room)   静かに歩く(walk quietly)
- 元気な女の子 (energetic girl)   元気に遊ぶ (play energetically)